# How do you execute a function call when clicked on dropdown menu on javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this menu. When I click on a dropdown item, I need to do something.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="float:right;">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
              <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">About</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Applications <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab"href="#test1">app1</a></li>
                <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab"href="#test2">app2</a></li>
                <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab"href="#test3">app3</a></li>
                <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#test4">app4</a></li>
                <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab"href="#test5">app5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
```

when I pick test1 from the dropdown menu, I need to do something, run a function.

I have done this:

```
<script>
$('#test1').on('click', function () {
  // do something…
  alert(this.val());
});
</script>
```

Does not seem to be working, no errors. Any ideas? I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: The selector `#test1` is looking for an element with the ID `test1`, not an href.  Change your selector to `$("a[href='#test1']").on....`, or simply give the `a` tags an id like `<a id="test1"...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$('a[href*="test1"]').on('click', function () {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

> The star designates that the proceeding value must appear somewhere in
>   the attribute's value.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/824f1351/6/)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling an ID that doesn't exist:

```
<li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab"href="#test1">app1</a></li>
```

You need to add an ID:

```
<li><a id="test1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"href="#test1">app1</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to grab the `href="#test"`. Use the  [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector. This will grab any element that has an href that begins with '#test':

Also you should change your this reference to `$(this)` and use `text()`, not `val()`.

```
$("a[href^='#test']").on('click', function () {
  // do something…
  alert($(this).text());
});
```